# Does Hibernate update an entity that has not changed?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Given an unchanged entity, does [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) [`session.update(entity)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#update%28java.lang.Object%29) send an [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) [`UPDATE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statement to the database server?

For example, in the following code, does Hibernate send an SQL `UPDATE` to the database server?

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Person me = new Person(null, "Derek Mahar");
session.save(me);
Person me2 = new Person(me.getId(), "Derek Mahar");
session.update(me2);
session.flush();
```

Comment: Does update even work if the object is still attached to a session? The API of `update()` tells that it updates a persistent instance with the given detached instance.

Comment: Kraftan, I think you may be correct.  According to the documentation, this example will throw an exception.  I'll modify the example so that it updates a detached instance having the same ID as the original.

Comment: cherouvim, not exactly a quiz.  It's a question about the efficiency of Hibernate update operations.

Comment: This may be a basic question, but you'd be surprised how many times I've seen code that first compares a persistent entity that it has just read from the database with a newly constructed detached object, and if they differ, attempts to invoke `session.update(detached)` to (eventually) persist the detached object to the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Strictly speaking, Hibernate does not send an SQL update on `update`. `update` simply updates the object in the current session. Hibernate executes queries when the session is flushed.

Comment: Bozho, you are correct, but my question was assuming a flush of the session after the last update.  My question was not explicit about this point, though, so I've modified the code example to include an explicit final `flush()`.

Comment: My answer was (and still is) "no" the rest was additional info :)

Comment: I am very late to the party. How does Hibernate check, if the entity has changed? We usually only have the ID in the equals methods of our `@Entity`.